# How can I prevent XML::XPath from fetching a DTD while processing an XML file?

Tags: xml, perl, dtd

My XML (**a.xhtml**) starts like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
...
```

My code starts like this

```
use XML::XPath;

use XML::XPath::XMLParser;

my $xp = XML::XPath->new(filename => "a.xhtml");

my $nodeset = $xp->find('/html/body//table');
```

It's very slow, and it turns out that it spends a lot of time getting the DTD (http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd).

Is there a way to explicitly declare an HTTP proxy server in the Perl XML:: family? I hate to modify the original **a.xhtml** document like having a local copy of the DTD.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

XML::XPath is based on XML::Parser. There is an option in XML::Parser to NOT use LWP to resolve external entities (such as DTDs). And XML::XPath lets you pass an XML::Parser objetc, to use as the parser.

So you can write this:

```
my $p = XML::Parser->new( NoLWP => 1);
my $xp= XML::XPath->new( parser => $p, filename => "a.xhtml");
```

Note that in this case you will loose all entities except numerical ones and the default ones (>, <, &, ' and "). The parser will not complain, but they will disappear silently (try including &alpha; in the table and printing it for example).

As a matter of fact you probably should not use XML::XPath, which is not actively maintained.

Try XML::LibXML, if you have no problem with installing libxml2, its interface is very similar to XML::XPath as they both implement the DOM. XML::LibXML is also much more powerful than XML::XPath, and faster to boot. If you want an expat/XML::Parser based module, they you might want to have a look at XML::Twig (that's blatant self-promotion as I am the author of the module, sorry). Also for HTML/dodgy XHTML, you can use HTML::TreeBuilder, which, with the addition of HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath (also by me), supports XPath.

Answer (score 3):

porneL's response seems to be the Right Thing here.  (www.w3.org has started taking 30 seconds to respond to each of my queries (when it doesn't just give up), and when XML::XPath ends up retrieving the full XHTML set…!)  Further, mirod's idea works, too:

```
use XML::XPath;
use XML::Catalog;

my $parser = new XML::Parser;
my $catalog_handler = new XML::Catalog("xhtml1-20020801/DTD/xhtml.soc")->get_handler($parser);
$parser->setHandlers("ExternEnt" => $catalog_handler);
my $xp = new XML::XPath(xml => $xml, parser => $parser);
```

Add a copy of "The complete set of DTD files together with an XML declaration and SGML Open Catalog" from ⟨URL:http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html⟩ and enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's done by setting up local [XML catalog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Catalog).

libxml-based parsers support it, so if you follow mirod's advice, you'll be able to get named entities and validation work without network access.

Comment: True. You could probably use XML::Catalog to add a catalog to an XML::Parser object, and use that parser in XML::XPath's new. I have never tested that though.